# Eager loading the first item from multiple value from a related table in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I have two tables 'purchases' and 'accounts_purchase_history'. purchase has many accounts history. So I need to get all the purchases with the latest history.
What i have done so far

```
 $purchases = Purchases::with(['accounts_purchase_historie' => function($query){
            return $query->orderBy('id','DESC')->first();
        }])->orderBy('id','DESC')->where('status','extended')->get();
```

But this query only gets the first purchase history, How can i solve this?

Comment: Do you want only the latest history for performance reasons? Or do you just want to avoid `$purchase->accounts_purchase_historie->first()`?

Comment: That query only returns the history for the first purchase, other purchase history are not returned. I only need the last history of a purchase, as in the process the purchase might be gone under several edit. So only the last edit history i want to get

Comment: If you remove `->first()` you can get the latest history with `$purchase->accounts_purchase_historie->first()`.

Comment: Yea then i will have to go through all the purchases again to get the latest history. I just thought if there any way to do it with a single query

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Can you please help me with another problem. In the pivot table the inputs get automatically ordered by the IDs. Is there any way to stop that automatic orders. For example I have a publication and a member table. say for example in publication number 20 three members are assigned, 3,2,5. But in pivot table they get ordered in 2,3,5

Comment: You want to sort them by their creation date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HasOne` relationship:

```
public function latest_history() {
    return $this->hasOne(...)->orderBy('id','DESC');
}

$purchases = Purchases::with('latest_history')
    ->orderBy('id','DESC')
    ->where('status','extended')
    ->get();

foreach($purchases as $purchase) {
    $purchase->latest_history
}
```

However, this will still fetch *all* the histories from the database in the background.

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?